# Most efficient way, Tags or List<GameObject>?

Tags: c#, performance, unity-game-engine

In my game I can use a list of game objects or tags to iterate but i prefer knows what is the most efficient way.

Save more memory using tags or unity requires many resources to do a search by tag?

```
public List<City> _Citys = new List<City>();
```

or

```
foreach(GameObject go in GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("City"))
```

Comment: The very first sentence for the tag [tag:Unity] is **"DO NOT USE ON QUESTIONS ABOUT THE UNITY GAME ENGINE (use: [tag:unity3d] instead)!!"**

Comment: On the foreach, you're doing the full research on the hierarchy each time. Store the result of `GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag` in a List for laters iterations, unless the result may change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're better of using a List of City objects and doing a standard for loop to iterate over the 'City' objects. The List just simply holds references to the 'City' objects, so impact on memory should be minimal - you could use an array of GameObjects[] instead of a List (which is what FindGameObjectsWithTag returns).

It's better for performance to use a populated List/Array rather than searching by Tags and of course you're explicitly pointing to an object rather than using 'magic' strings -- if you change the tag name later on then the FindGameObjectsWithTag method will silently break, as it will no longer find any objects.

[Also, avoid using a foreach loop in Unity as this unfortunately creates a lot of garbage (the garbage collector in Unity isn't great so it's best to create as little garbage as possbile), instead just use a standard for loop:](http://www.gamasutra.com/blogs/AmirFassihi/20130828/199134/0__60_fps_in_14_days_What_we_learned_trying_to_optimize_our_game_using_Unity3D.php)

> Replace the “foreach” loops with simple “for” loops. For some reason, every iteration of every “foreach” loop generated 24 Bytes of garbage memory. A simple loop iterating 10 times left 240 Bytes of memory ready to be collected which was just unacceptable

EDIT: As mentioned in pid's answer - measure. You can use the built-in Unity profiler to inspect memory usage: http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ProfilerMemory.html

Answer (score 1):

Per Microsoft's C# API rules, verbs such as `Find*` or `Count*` denote active code while terms such as `Length` stand for actual values that require no code execution.

Now, if the Unity3D folks respected those guidelines is a matter of debate, but from the name of the method I can already tell that it has a cost and should not be taken too lightly.

On the other side, your question is about performance, not correctness. Both ways are correct *per se*, but one is supposed to have better performance.

So, the main rule of refactoring for performance is: **MEASURE**.

It depends on memory allocation and garbage collection, it is impossible to tell which really is faster without measuring.

So the best advice I could give you is pretty general. Whenever you feel the need to enhance performance of code you have to actually measure what you are about to improve, before and after.

Comment: since the method your are referring to is called once, the key isn't whether is "active" code but how long it will take to find all objects with the given tag. How long that would take depends on the implementation of the method and since that might be implemented as O(n) it could be fast but it could also easily be O(n)

Comment: Yes, that's the danger with properties and hidden complexity and that's why I said measuring is so important! Thanks for explaining this important point.

Answer (score 1):

Few ways I would consider:

- at the start of the scene you collect the items you want by Tags.
  And save them to a list - cache. It may be slow, but it runs only at the beginning.
- The objects registers themselves to your cache. They all need a little script.

Answer (score 0):

Your code examples are 2 distinctly different things. One is instantiating a list, and one is enumerating over an IEnumerable returned from a function call.

I assume you mean the difference between iterating over your declared list vs iterating over the return value from GameObject.FindObjectsWithTag() in which case;

Storing a List as a member variable in your class, populating it once and then iterating over it several times is more efficient than iterating over GameObject.FindObjectsWithTag several times.

This is because you keep your List and your references to the objects in your list at all times without having to repopulate it.

GameObject.FindObjectsWithTag will search your entire object hierarchy and compile a list of all the objects that it finds that matches your search criteria. This is done every time you call the function, so there is additional overhead even if the amount of objects it finds is the same as it still searches your hierarchy.

To be honest, you could just cache your results with a List object using GameObject.FindObjectWithTag providing the amount of objects returned will not change. (As in to say you are not instantiating or destroying any of those objects)